# Replace period with comma between author and year in bibliography, using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biblatex-chicago

Using
`\usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex8,babel=other,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}`

my bibliography looks like this:
[image]

However, the citation norm I need to use requires a comma between author's name and the year, so I am trying to achieve

> GOLEMAN, Daniel, 2014. *Pozornost*. Brno: Jan Melvil publishing. ISBN: 8087270943.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to modify `biblatex-chicago` without undesired side-effects, but this will probably work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{goleman2014,
  author = {Goleman, Daniel},
  date = {2014},
  title = {Pozornost},
  location = {Brno},
  publisher = {Jan Melvil publishing},
  isbn = {8087270943}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}{%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]